# Setting the value of a radio button

Tags: forms, meteor

So I am trying to set the value of the radio buttons on an edit form. I tried using jQuery to run an if statement then using a selector to set the checked property. But I guess I dont understand how jQuery and Template.template.helpers work together because I could never get jQuery to do anything.

Anyways, I got the following to work, but I am just curios if this is the best way to do it. This just seems way bloated for something as simple as setting the values of radio buttons in a form. I guess there might be package that works for forms better.

Here is the Javascript

```
Template.clientEdit.helpers({

    // set the radio buttons
    isActive: function() {
        if (this.status == "active") {
            return "checked";
        }
    },

    isArchived: function() {
        if (this.status == "archived") {
            return "checked";
        }
    },
});
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status-radio-1" value="active" {{isActive}} >
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status-radio-2" value="archived" {{isArchived}} >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a global handlebars helper, to use across all your Meteor forms, eg:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checked_eq', function(x, y){
  if (x === y){
     return ' checked="checked"';
  }
  return ''
})
```

And use it in your templates like:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status-radio-1" value="active" {{checked_eq status 'active'}} >
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status-radio-2" value="archived" {{checked_eq status 'archived'}} >
```

You could also write something a bit more generic, eg:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'checked', (x)-> if x then ' checked="checked"' else ''
Handlebars.registerHelper 'notChecked', (x)-> if x then '' else ' checked="checked"'
# repeat for disabled / selected etc
```

And apply a transform too your data/ dataContext before rendering your template:

```
 // ...  using iron-router for data contet
 data: function(){
   var client = Clients.findOne(this.params.clientId);
   client.checkedActive = (client.status == 'active');
   client.checkedArchived = (client.status == 'archived');
   return client;
 }
 // ...

 // ... or apply a transform when making a list
 Template.clientList.helpers({
    clients: function(){
      return Clients.find({},{
        transform: function(client){
           client.checkedActive = (client.status == 'active');
           client.checkedArchived = (client.status == 'archived');
           return client;
        }
      });
    }
 });
```

Then use in your templates like:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status-radio-1" value="active" {{checked checkedActive}} >
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status-radio-2" value="archived" {{checked checkedArchived}} >
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks. I am guessing that the Handlebar helper files could go anywhere, but is there a best practice for organizing these kinds of files?

Comment: Well, best practice is to split any reasonably sized application in to packages! So I make a bunch of `app-xx` based packages, eg `app-ui-handlebars` and stuff the relevant files in there.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this and couldn't get it to work - very close but it prevented the template from loading so based on [this](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers/pull/59) I used the following which worked like a charm:

```
Template.registerHelper('checkedRadio', function(x, y){
    return (x === y) ? { checked: 'checked' } : null;
});
```